# Application setting page opening twice Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

```
try {
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           Toast.makeText(AppSettings.this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

I have tried above code to open Notification Setting of my App, but when I am clicking back button from the same screen (Notification Setting), I am again getting the same screen. Any suggestion for the same????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `android:launchMode` is what you are looking for. By default it is `standard` so it creates a new instance of activity every time. You should try to use `singleTop`. More details you can find here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.